# tabBar color difference

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitabbar

For some reason my iPhone/Simulator incorrectly interprets the black when I assign it to the tabBar.

[image]

UITabBar:

```swift
func setupViewController(){
    tabBar.barTintColor = .black
 }
```

The custom button:

```swift
func setupMiddleButton() {
    let menuButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 74, height: 74))

    ...

    menuButton.backgroundColor = .black
    tabBar.addSubview(menuButton)
}
```

I'd like that the tabBar color is true black (#000000) as the round button. I also tested it with other colors, the problem (difference) is the same.  Any hint would be very kind!

Comment: Try setting [`tabBar.isTranslucent`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbar/1623458-istranslucent) to `false`.

Comment: great, that was the trick! thanks a lot!